# Using a ScriptManager in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, scriptmanager

Must be a simple question, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to include a script manager in my view. `<asp:ScriptManager />` doesn't work. Anyone know?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ScriptManager is a webforms specific construct, so if you are using MVC, you won't (and shouldn't) be able to use it.  You can look at http://mvcscriptmanager.codeplex.com/ if you want something that ports some of the features of the scriptmanager to MVC.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar situation upgrading a project.
For "simple-ish" WCF Ajax services, I was able to get this work by adding:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Services/SampleService.svc/jsdebug")"></script>
```

and then create my service object the old fashion way:

```
var dataService = new SampleService();
dataService.doBar(fooCallback,fooErrorMethod,null);
```

I haven't tested this is extensively, but Hey, isn't that why the word "kludge" became an official developer term.